# How do I manage contacts from multple accounts (twitter, facebook, gmail, etc,.)?

Tags: sync, gmail, contacts, web-application

I have quite a few of online accounts that I use that have contacts within them.  Here are a few examples:

- Gmail (4 accts)
- Google+
- FaceBook
- LinkedIn
- Outlook.com
- The list goes on

Within these accounts there some contacts that are unique (i.e. Person A is only found on LinkedIn and Person B is only found on Facebook) and there are a lot of contacts that are the same (i.e. Person C can be found within Facebook, Gmail, Outlook.com, etc,.).

### The Problem

The issue that I'm running into is that these contacts are fragmented and not synchronized.  For example, Person C has three different sets of information:

```
Fragmented Info:

PersonC (Facebook)  PersonC (Gmail)     PersonC (Outlook.com)
- FB Profile        - G+ Profile        - Email 2
- Email 1           - Email 1           - Address
- Phone
```

With multiple devices that access these accounts, I would like to have a way where all my contacts are synchronized and merged with each other for all of my devices that I use (computer, phone, tablet, etc,.):

```
Merged Info:

PersonC
- FB Profile
- Email 1
- Email 2
- G+ Profile
- Address
- Phone
```

How do I have all of my contacts in a centralized area that synchronizes and merges for most, if not all of my devices?

*Note: If you decide to answer with a software recommendation, please read over [this meta post first.](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225)*

Comment: What you need is something which can consume contact information from all your sources, merge it into a single complete record per person, and then produce that data to be consumed by your desktop mail client, phone, tablet, &c. On the one hand, it's very doubtful that such software exists, meaning you're going to need to write code to make it happen; on the other, it's similarly unlikely that all your data sources will be able to consume your authoritative representation, meaning you'll only be able to go so far in solving the problem no matter what you do.

Comment: @AaronMiller I understand that services like twitter aren't going to have an email address, or address or whatever associated with it and therefore won't be able to be merged with the meta data of all the others, however the contacts on my computer, phone and web services like gmail do.  I'm looking to have all of that information synchronized together.

Comment: You're rather missing my point. What I'm saying isn't that not every service will have the same information, which is trivially obvious, but instead that the first thing you need to do is investigate and confirm that everything, which you want to consume the combined representation of your contacts, is capable of doing so in some format or other -- and the *second* thing you need to do is start planning how you're going to write code to pull in contact info from all those services, synchronize it, and output it in whatever combination of formats all your consumers can understand.

Comment: @AaronMiller the whole point of asking this question is to discover if there is a way of doing this without programming the whole thing.  Small amounts of programming (scripts) is ok, but I'd rather have a service, software that can do this for me.

Comment: That would be nice, wouldn't it? The purpose in which I've commented is to elucidate the scale of the problem you describe, which is quite a lot more complex than I suspect you've considered, to substantiate my assertion that no such software or service presently exists. There are a bunch of workarounds, at least some of which I'm sure you encountered in your research, but they all suck to a greater or lesser degree; if one of them answered your purpose, I assume you wouldn't have posted your question, whose answer is "you pretty much need to write the contacts equivalent of `sendmail`".

Comment: You mean something like http://www.fullcontact.com/features/sync-google-contacts/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the only way this would work is if these services offer the feature to merge with other said services;

This means that unless the services you are mentioning (GMail, LinkedIn, etc.) actually had this feature, it's not possible to do it without either:

1) Finding a piece of software that would both merge and manage your information through each of the services API's.

or

2) Learning the API's of said services and making your own software.